# Sabre PassengerDetailsRQ failing with Invalid Version Number error

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl, sabre

I am trying to make booking by using OTA_AirBookLLSRQ followed by PassengerDetailsRQ. I am able to succeed in OTA_AirBookLLSRQ, however failing in PassengerDetailsRQ with below error.

I am pointing to Sabre CERT environment and getting this problem.

Please help me in pointing what is wrong with my request.

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Invalid service version    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action,
>   Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)

The request xmls for PassengerDetailsRQ are

MessageHeader

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MessageHeader xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" d1p1:version="2.0" xmlns:d1p1="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
    <d1p1:From>
        <d1p1:PartyId>99999</d1p1:PartyId>
    </d1p1:From>
    <d1p1:To>
        <d1p1:PartyId>123123</d1p1:PartyId>
    </d1p1:To>
    <d1p1:CPAId>TestCPA</d1p1:CPAId>
    <d1p1:ConversationId>20171024T155602Z</d1p1:ConversationId>
    <d1p1:Service>PassengerDetailsRQ</d1p1:Service>
    <d1p1:Action>PassengerDetailsRQ</d1p1:Action>
    <d1p1:MessageData>
        <d1p1:MessageId>mid:20171024T155602Z@clientofsabre.com</d1p1:MessageId>
        <d1p1:Timestamp>20171024T155602Z</d1p1:Timestamp>
    </d1p1:MessageData>
</MessageHeader>
```

Security Object

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Security xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <BinarySecurityToken xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/CERTG!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!-3218433817369427567!1447734!0</BinarySecurityToken>
</Security>
```

PassengerDetailsRQ

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<PassengerDetailsRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <PostProcessing xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3">
        <EndTransactionRQ>
            <EndTransaction Ind="true" />
            <Source ReceivedFrom="Oneworld RTW" />
        </EndTransactionRQ>
    </PostProcessing>
    <SpecialReqDetails xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3">
        <SpecialServiceRQ>
            <SpecialServiceInfo>
                <AdvancePassenger SegmentNumber="A">
                    <PersonName NameNumber="1.1">
                        <GivenName>Narasimham</GivenName>
                        <MiddleName>Venkata Lakshmi</MiddleName>
                        <Surname>Akella</Surname>
                    </PersonName>
                </AdvancePassenger>
            </SpecialServiceInfo>
        </SpecialServiceRQ>
    </SpecialReqDetails>
    <TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ xmlns="http://services.sabre.com/sp/pd/v3_3">
        <CustomerInfo> 
            <PersonName NameNumber="1.1" PassengerType="ADT">
                <GivenName>Narasimham</GivenName>
                <Surname>Akella</Surname>
            </PersonName>
        </CustomerInfo>
    </TravelItineraryAddInfoRQ>
</PassengerDetailsRQ>
```

Code for placing the request through SOAP proxy class

```
PassengerDetails.PassengerDetailsPortTypeClient paxDetCli = new PassengerDetails.PassengerDetailsPortTypeClient("PassengerDetailsPortType1" + envName);
                Task<PassengerDetails.PassengerDetailsRQResponse> resp = paxDetCli.PassengerDetailsRQAsync(msgHeader, security, paxDetReq);
                resp.Wait();
                txtResult.Text += "Sucess Response:" + SerializeObject(typeof(PassengerDetails.PassengerDetailsRQResponse), resp.Result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error pretty much says it all; version declaration is missing in this case.

You should add `version="3.3.0"` to the service request's header.

Comment: Adding version as 3.3.0 in PassengerDetailsRQ did the magic.  Thank you for the help. I wonder why only PassengerDetailsRQ has the version error, where as in other call i didn't pass the version at request body level.